# SQL select average grade for students

Tags: mysql, average

I'm learning sql and I'm having a bit of trouble with this,
I need the average grade of every student on each subject.

I made the following  tables.

```
students
|id_student|name|

subjects
|id_subject|name|

grades
|id_grade|value|
```

And im linking them using these tables:

```
students_subjects
|id_student|id_subject|

subjects_grades
|id_subject|id_grade|

students_grades
|id_student|id_grade|
```

Any help appreciated

I'm trying

```
SELECT students.name, subjects.name, grades.value
FROM students
INNER JOIN students_subjects
ON students.id_student = students_subjects.id_student
INNER JOIN subjects
ON subjects.id_subject = students_subjects.id_subject
INNER JOIN students_grades
ON students_grades.id_student = students.id_student
INNER JOIN grades
ON students_grades.id_grade = grades.id_grade
INNER JOIN subjects_grades
ON grades.id_grade = subjects_grades.id_grade
```

And i get the following table

```
|     name |    name | value |
|----------|---------|-------|
|     Nico |  class1 |    70 |
|     Nico |  class1 |    40 |
|     Nico |  class2 |    70 |
|     Nico |  class2 |    40 |
|    Fadia |  class1 |    60 |
|    Fadia |  class1 |    55 |
| Cristian |  class2 |    50 |
| Cristian |  class2 |    40 |
```

But if i do AVG(grades.value) I only get the first row

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Could you clarify if you want average grades for each student or for each subject?

Comment: the average of each student in every subject. eg, for one student, their average in subject1, subject2, etc. That for every student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a group by:

```
SELECT students.name, subjects.name, AVG(grades.value)
FROM students
    INNER JOIN students_subjects
    ON students.id_student = students_subjects.id_student
    INNER JOIN subjects
    ON subjects.id_subject = students_subjects.id_subject
    INNER JOIN students_grades
    ON students_grades.id_student = students.id_student
    INNER JOIN grades
    ON students_grades.id_grade = grades.id_grade
    INNER JOIN subjects_grades
    ON grades.id_grade = subjects_grades.id_grade
GROUP BY students.name, subjects.name
```